# How can I find out what collapsable accordation is clicked?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following Bootstrap 5 accordian, I need to know what panel is clicked on and currently visible. How can I do that? This is what I have so far:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
    <div class="accordion-item">
        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
            <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                panel 1
            </button>
        </h2>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="accordion-body"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordion-item">
        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
            <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="headingTwo">
                panel 2
            </button>
        </h2>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="accordion-body"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $('#accordionExample').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
        //call a service here 
        //alert("inne");
        alert($(this).text());
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a snippet using [the example accordian HTML from the Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/accordion/).  Accordians use [`collapse`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/collapse/); each of [the `collapse` events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/collapse/#events) will receive the event as a parameter.  So if you add handlers for the `shown` and `hidden` events, you can then find the `event.target`, which will be what was clicked.  And from that, with a little logic, you can work out what is currently visible, or hidden.

```js
$('#accordionExample').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    let clicked = $(e.target).attr('id');
    alert(clicked + ' was clicked and is now visible');
});

$('#accordionExample').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    let clicked = $(e.target).attr('id');
    alert(clicked + ' was clicked and is now hidden');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        Accordion Item #1
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
        Accordion Item #2
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingThree">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
        Accordion Item #3
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the third item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```